# How to properly handle errors on the server?

Tags: node.js, express

How to properly handle errors on the server?

```
if (!user) throw Error("User does not exist");
```

```
if (!user) {
 return res.status(400).json({
  msg: User does not exist
 })
}
```

```
if (!user) {
 res.status(400).json({msg: User does not exist})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're a server dealing with a client, setting `status` is a must.
So in my opinion you shuld pick option `2`.

Besides, if `user` is a resource client is requesting and it does not exist , status code better to be `404`.

Comment: Questions asking for opinion are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]